# Django: Convert python dict having objects to json

Tags: django, python-3.x

I've a node object as :

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name=None, parent=None):
        self._name = name
        self._parent = parent
        self._children = set()
```

and I've a dictionary having a id(str) as key and this node object as value
e.g.

```
rec_dict[rec_id] = Node(rec_name, parent)
```

After creating this rec_dict. I want to save it to a session to serve multiple django requests. i'm getting following error while doing:

```
request.session['rec_dict'] = rec_dict

TypeError: <Node object at 0x7f6b066361d0> is not JSON serializable
```

I've also tried

```
json.dumps(rec_dict)
```

and

```
serializer.serialize(rec_dict)
```

But none of them is working as value is a node object. Please tell me how to store this rec_dict in session or any workaround to do the same. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Django defaults to serializing sessions in `JSON`. If you **absolutely must** support storing complex objects in session variables, you can change the session serializer to [`django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#session-serializer) by defining it in `settings.py`:

```
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'
```

Whenever possible it is better to store simple identifiers in the session, e.g. a primary key or some sort of natural keys that you could use to recreate the needed object at runtime.

---

**Pickle**

`Pickle` is specialized in serializing all things Python. However, there is this big red warning [on the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pickle.html):

> The pickle module is not intended to be secure against erroneous or
>   maliciously constructed data. Never unpickle data received from an
>   untrusted or unauthenticated source.

Pickle imposes security risks to which web applications by their interactive nature are often vulnerable against. That's why in many widely used apps/packages like `Django` or `Celery`, it was removed as a default and only left in as an option.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really be storing model instances in the session. Even if you did manage to serialise them successfully, when you deserialised them later in another view you would get the values as they were originally, even if the data in the db has changed in the meantime.

Instead, store the IDs, and get them back from the db when you need to.